# Maven aggregation build uses different java than building a child module on its own

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I noticed an unexpected behavior. I have an aggregation POM for the purposes of aggregated goals execution.

When I execute the build task, the modules included in aggregation POM have their javadoc generated. The javadoc generation is defined in parent POM (not the same as aggregation POM) like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The child module has its own POM, in which an aspectJ plugin is defined like this: (this is how the build tag actually looks like as a whole in the child POM:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <complianceLevel>1.7</complianceLevel>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Now, when I run the aggregation build, it generates javadocs with Java 1.8 (there is no mention about which java to use in aggregation POM):

```
Constructing Javadoc information...
Standard Doclet version 1.8.0
Building tree for all the packages and classes...
...
12 errors
16 warnings
```

But when I run build just on the child module, it will use Java 1.7.0_45

```
Constructing Javadoc information...
Standard Doclet version 1.7.0_45
Building tree for all the packages and classes...
...
2 warnings
```

Why this inconsistency? I would expect that the build should work the same. Am I doing something wrong? How does one configure the aggregation build to use the configuration of the child module (with its POM), which to me seems the way which should be default.

My assumption is that aggregation build is the same thing as running "install" goal on each child module manually as if on a seperate project. Is this assumption wrong? (seems like it is, since this behaviour) If yes, what is actually happening?

If information are missing (parts of pom configurations) please comment.

Comment: First how have you exactly called those builds? Do all childs use the same parent as your aggregator?

Comment: My aggregator does not use the parent. But all child modules do use the parent. Is this what is missing? I thought that if child has the parent than it always has to be included in the build. 

I called the builds using netbeans build. In all cases. I presume this just runs install goal on the project. In the case of aggregation module this runs build recursively on submodules.

Comment: @khmarbaise was that information helpful?